# How do I change the colouring of my Beamer template?

Tags: beamer, templates

Okay. I am trying to change the colour of my beamer template. I am using Copenhagen and wolverine.

Here is what the slides look like, as well as the code I am using.

[image]

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty   % Removes the interactive buttons
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}  % Removes the header sections

% ADDS SLIDE NUMBERS
%\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
%\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
%\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
%   \oldmacro\hfill%
%   \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

% Additional packages needed
\usepackage{amsmath} % For ???
\usepackage{dsfont}  % For mathds font
\usepackage{hologo}  % For BibTeX font
\usepackage{lmodern} % For ???

%Information to be included in the title page:
 \title{Central Bank Watching}

 \author{NAME}

 \institute[University]
 {
   University \newline \newline March 2019
 }

\date[\today]{}

\titlegraphic{\flushleft \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{UNI.png}}

% The below defines the footer such that it is:
% First Last (Institution) || Title           frame / frame total
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~(\insertshortinstitute)
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

% The below is used for creating section pages
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{part title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{centering}
}
% \setbeamertemplate{section page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}[plain,c]
        \sectionpage
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

...

\end{document}
```

I'd like to change the yellow to the following RGB: 69, 91, 196

and the orange to the following RGB: 168, 178, 85

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're changing yellow to a blue, and orange to a green, then why are you starting with that color theme?

Comment: @Teepeemm, to my knowledge, there isn't a blue/green theme combo that exists already? Also I changed universities, and Copenhagen/wolverine theme worked nicely with my former university's colours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding

```
\definecolor{aa}{RGB}{69, 91, 196}
\definecolor{bb}{RGB}{168, 178, 85}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=aa}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{bg=bb}
```

does the trick.

Alternatively you could manually change individual colors like this:

```
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=aa}
```

But this requires a lot more trial and error if you don't know how your particular template is set-up.

[image]

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty   % Removes the interactive buttons
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}  % Removes the header sections

\definecolor{aa}{RGB}{69, 91, 196}
\definecolor{bb}{RGB}{168, 178, 85}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=aa}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{bg=bb}



% ADDS SLIDE NUMBERS
%\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
%\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
%\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
%   \oldmacro\hfill%
%   \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

% Additional packages needed
\usepackage{amsmath} % For ???
\usepackage{dsfont}  % For mathds font
\usepackage{hologo}  % For BibTeX font
\usepackage{lmodern} % For ???

%Information to be included in the title page:
 \title{Central Bank Watching}

 \author{NAME}

 \institute[University]
 {
     University \newline \newline March 2019
 }

\date[\today]{}

\titlegraphic{\flushleft \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{UNI.png}}

% The below defines the footer such that it is:
% First Last (Institution) || Title           frame / frame total
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~(\insertshortinstitute)
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}

% The below is used for creating section pages
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
        \begin{centering}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{part title}
        \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \end{centering}
}
% \setbeamertemplate{section page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[]{
        \begin{frame}[plain,c]
                \sectionpage
        \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. But the yellow bit where "Outline" is stays yellow. I'd like that to be the blue as well if possible. Also, how do I change the font colour of the header and also the Central Bank Watching to be in white? So it is easier to read against the blue background.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "where Outline is". But I guess you can play around with `palette secondary` or `palette secondary`. Concerning the font I am reasonable positive that this would be defined by `fg=` instead of `bg=`

Comment: The "outline" is in the original image, so it is header of the normal slides (not title slide). Thanks, I'll give the "fg" a go.

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay attention to the first picture, only to your code. The "outline" seems to be the title of the next frame. Then you should be able to change that with `\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=aa}`

Comment: I suggest one small addition: `\usecolortheme[named=aa]{structure}` before you load the copenhagen theme to ensure that there will be no nasty colour clashes with the elements that would still have the default beamer blue colour, e.g. with things like `\structure{text}` etc.